# How to link a local file on my personal portfolio?

Tags: html, css, web, portfolio

I am trying to link my resume (on my local drive) to my portfolio, but it does not work after I deploy it. It only worked in preview for some reason, but now nothing is showing at all.

`<a href="File:///Users/My Name/Desktop/portfolioo/Name's resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a>`

Does anyone know what's going on here? I am just getting started in web design, so any help is much appreciated!

I wanted to create a link to my resume that would open up on another tab. IT WORKS IN THE COPY PATH PREVIEW FROM VISUAL STUDIO, but not when I deploy it to my website. This link is on my navigation at the top, so I wonder if my nav can only go to pages that are linked to my Github?

Comment: Share some code please

Comment: Just made the edit. Thank you

Comment: It works in preview because VS can access your local hard drive...  A website on "the internet" cannot.  You will need to upload the PDF, to a home on the web and link to that address.  You may consider taking a tutorial on web/app deployment before putting it in your portfolio.  Understanding where files are stored and how they are accessed is a very important part of development.

Comment: I'm a UX person. I am just trying to learn more about development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your website to a web server, the file paths to local files on your computer will not work anymore. The File:/// protocol is specific to local file access on your computer, and it won't be accessible from a different computer or when your website is deployed online.

To fix this issue, you need to make your resume file accessible on the web.

1. Upload your resume file to your website's server or to a file hosting service. Using FTP, Dropbox or Google Drive.
2. Once your resume file is uploaded, you need to update the link in your portfolio to point to the online location of the file.

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/resume/Name's%20resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a>
```

Remember to test the link after making these changes to ensure it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your portfolio page on web, then the resume file stored in the local storage will not be accessible. To overcome this Upload your file in cloud
, like Google Drive, DropBox and generate the link for it, Then

`<a href="//Paste the Generated Link" target="_blank">Resume</a>`

Hope this would be helpful!